# Does python's hash function remain identical across different versions?

Tags: python, hash, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I'm currently using `hash` on tuples of integers and strings (and nested tuples of integers and strings etc.) in order to compute the uniqueness of some objects. Barring that there might be a hash collisions, I wonder - is the `hash` function on those data types guaranteed to return the same result for different versions of Python?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Apart from long-standing differences between 32- and 64-bit versions of Python, the hashing algorithm [was changed in Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) to resolve a security issue:

> By default, the **hash**() values of str, bytes and datetime objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python.
>
> This is intended to provide protection against a denial-of-service caused by carefully-chosen inputs that exploit the worst case performance of a dict insertion, O(n^2) complexity. See http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html for details.
>
> Changing hash values affects the iteration order of dicts, sets and other mappings. Python has never made guarantees about this ordering (and it typically varies between 32-bit and 64-bit builds).

As a result, from 3.3 onwards `hash()` is not even guaranteed to return the same result across different invocations of the same Python version.

Comment: that would be my answer then! thanks, I will find another way.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but you can always use [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) if you're looking for consistent hashing.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> t = ("values", "other")
>>> hashlib.sha256(str(t).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
'bc3ed71325acf1386b40aa762b661bb63bb72e6df9457b838a2ea93c95cc8f0c'
```

OR:

```
>>> h = hashlib.sha256()
>>> for item in t:
...     h.update(item.encode("utf-8"))
...
>>> h.hexdigest()
'5e98df135627bc8d98250ca7e638aeb2ccf7981ce50ee16ce00d4f23efada068'
```

Answer (score 2):

No. eg.

32 bit

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hash("foobar")
-1969371895
```

64 bit

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hash("foobar")
3433925302934160649
```

Comment: This is misleading since it has nothing to do with 32 vs 64 bit. You can run `python -c "print(hash('foobar'))"` multiple times and see that the hash value is different every time.

Comment: @dhg, this answer is from 9 years ago. At that time plenty of people were using Python versions older than 3.3 (when the hash behaviour changed) and if you try this on python2.7 you will get the same value every time.